# Group and reduce to keep only 'best' in each group

Tags: javascript

I have price rule data as an array of objects with minimum quantity to which that rule applies. I need to output an array of objects where only the lowest prices are kept for each minimum quantity group. Furthermore, if for a price rule there exists a lower price in a lower minimum quantity group, the rule shouldn't be saved.

I have currently implemented a very ugly and verbose way to do this with both .sort and .reduce array methods. Could anyone guide me in making this more elegant and possibly faster? This will be most likely be run on arrays ~10-100 objects but many times over to iterate over customers.

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  min_qty: 0,
  unit_price: 3.5
}, {
  id: 2,
  min_qty: 0,
  unit_price: 3.2
}, {
  id: 3,
  min_qty: 5,
  unit_price: 2.9
}, {
  id: 4,
  min_qty: 0,
  unit_price: 3.1
}, {
  id: 5,
  min_qty: 10,
  unit_price: 3.7
}]

data.sort((a, b) => {
  const {
    unit_price: aUnitPrice,
    min_qty: aMinQty
  } = a;
  const {
    unit_price: bUnitPrice,
    min_qty: bMinQty
  } = b;

  if (aMinQty > bMinQty) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (aMinQty < bMinQty) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (aUnitPrice > bUnitPrice) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (aUnitPrice < bUnitPrice) {
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
})

const calculatedPrices = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (acc[acc.length - 1]?.unit_price < el.unit_price) {
    return acc;
  }
  acc.push(el);
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log('---Incoming data---');
console.log(data);
console.log('---Processed data---');
console.log(calculatedPrices);
```

Comment: This might be me being thick but I cannot work out how your results are expected. You said `I need to output an array of objects where only the best prices are kept.` - how do you define "best prices"? Also for working code [codereview.se] is often better

Comment: I would agree with @Jamiec : what's the criteria for 'best price'?

Comment: Fair point. I updated the question to reflect that lower prices are better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the requirement correctly (which I'm not convinced I do!) then you're looking to essentially do a group-by on the `min_qty` but only keep the lowest `unit_price` record.

If correct, this would be doable without the sort:

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  min_qty: 0,
  unit_price: 3.5
}, {
  id: 2,
  min_qty: 0,
  unit_price: 3.2
}, {
  id: 3,
  min_qty: 5,
  unit_price: 2.9
}, {
  id: 4,
  min_qty: 0,
  unit_price: 3.1
}, {
  id: 5,
  min_qty: 10,
  unit_price: 3.7
}]

const isPriceHigherThanLowerMinQtys = (map, x) => {
  for(var i=x.min_qty-1;i>=0;i--){
     if(map[i] && map[i].unit_price < x.unit_price)
      return false;
  }
  return true
}

const result = Object.values(data.reduce( (acc,i) => {
   if((!acc[i.min_qty] || acc[i.min_qty].unit_price > i.unit_price) && isPriceHigherThanLowerMinQtys(acc,i)) {
      acc[i.min_qty] = i;
   }
   return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Check the updated question body.
The reduce function also needs to skip rules that have higher price than any rule at lower min_qty. The verbose code I posted fulfills this restriction.

Comment: @Helv can you add some input data to demonstrate this rule? Of course my code currently gives same output as yours so Im not sure even if I implemented it id get it right

Comment: I've added another entry to the incoming data. Now the object with id 5 shouldn't make it in the result as it's price is higher than on lower minimum quantities, even though it has the best (and only) price within it's own minimum quantity.

Comment: @Helv see if that update solves it for you?

Comment: What I'm starting to think is that the isPriceHigherThanLowerMinQtys doesn't need a for loop as it really needs to compare only with the last value. Thanks for the input. The function works as expected.
Nevermind, I misunderstood why it was required. It's actually needed.